# Failure to find org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:sources:2.47.2

Tags: java, maven, selenium

What maven repository to be able to download the `selenium-java:jar:sources`?

I have tried maven central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
and JCenter all failed to have the sources jar.

Specifically needed 2.72.2 as libraries in my project depends on it.

Comment: Also did this `mvn package -U -Dselenium.version=3.0.0 -f pom.xml` but it won't override the child `POM`s

Comment: Its seems sources is not published in maven repo for 2.47.2 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.47.2/  Its available in almost all the 3.X.X versions https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java